# How to get all children documents using $graphLookup of MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphlookup

I have this data as below in two collections of MongoDB.
categories:

```
[
  { "_id" : 1, "name" : "A" },
  { "_id" : 2, "name" : "B", "categoryId" : 1 },
  { "_id" : 3, "name" : "C", "categoryId" : 1 },
  { "_id" : 4, "name" : "D", "categoryId" : 2 },
  { "_id" : 5, "name" : "E", "categoryId" : 3 },
  { "_id" : 6, "name" : "F", "categoryId" : 2 }
];
```

And I have **Locos** documents:

```
[
  { "_id" : 1, "name" : "X", "categoryId" : 2 },
  { "_id" : 2, "name" : "Y", "categoryId" : 3 },
  { "_id" : 2, "name" : "B", "categoryId" : 1 } 
]
```

For example if I want to get all the chilren of category **A** which has the id **1**, i call the function and it returns an array of ids of children categories and if possible the Locos chilren. So the result will be like this:

```
chilren: {
          categories: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
          locos: [1, 2, 3]
         }
```

If i call the function with the id **2** which is category **B**, I get the result:

```
chilren: {
          categories: [2, 6],
          locos: [1]
         }
```

Comment: your sample document does not match your code. I presume your sample document for `categories` and `locos` are masked. Can you provide valid sample data and the corresponding expected output?

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, I fixed the question as you asked.
we can have the result without containing it in "children". just two arrays

Comment: because the first category with the id 1 is the parent of all categories hence it is a parent of all locos because the locos are children of categories that are children of that first category. I hope it makes sense to you.
I want the locos to be considerate as children of categories in case I am looking for any kind of children for a certain category.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track to use `$graphLookup`.

```js
db.categories.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      _id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "categories",
      "startWith": "$_id",
      "connectFromField": "_id",
      "connectToField": "categoryId",
      "as": "categoryLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "locos",
      "startWith": "$_id",
      "connectFromField": "_id",
      "connectToField": "categoryId",
      "as": "locosLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      children: {
        categories: {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$categoryLookup",
            "as": "c",
            "in": "$$c._id"
          }
        },
        locos: {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$locosLookup",
            "as": "l",
            "in": "$$l._id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pjAM1JbizlF) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you so much but It's not accurate on the locos document.. I changed the Id to 2 in the query and it returned all the locos :/

Comment: I guess you don't need the graphlookup on the locos since they don't have hierarchie ..

Comment: @Sara if `locos` does not have hierarchy, then why category A will expect [1, 2, 3] for `children.locos`?

Comment: because the first category with the id 1 is the parent of all categories hence it is a parent of all locos because the locos are children of categories that are children of that first category. I hope it makes sense to you. I want the locos to be considerate as children of categories in case I am looking for any kind of children for a certain category. thanks

Comment: to correct my input; yes you need graphlookup for locos but while looking for categories:
I mean that for each descendant category we need to check if it has a template so we add it to the array.
Thanks again for taking me seriously and I will mark it as useful answer ;)

Comment: @Sara is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kiqE50pOTa0) what you are looking for? It is very confusing that in category A example, `id 1` is not included in the categories array while `id 2` is included in category B example. Would be helpful if you can give more explanation on that.

Comment: How to unwind the given id ?

Comment: @Sara it is not very specific for "how to unwind the given id". Can you give the expected output so we know how we can help?

Comment: it's okey
i can manage the rest
thank you so much